# “Warning: comparison is always true”

Tags: c++, templates, comparison

GCC (4.7.2) with `-Wextra` signals the following warning/error (I have `-Werror` enabled):

> Comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]

for the following code [[try online](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=aac8b4042417d0f52ff51586eb67492d)]:

```
template <
    typename T,
    std::size_t N,
    bool = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) < N>
struct validator {
    static constexpr bool validate(T value) {
        return static_cast<std::size_t>(value) < N;
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct validator<T, N, true> {
    static constexpr bool validate(T) {
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Works
    static_assert(validator<int, 4>::validate(3), "Invalid");
    // Error :-(
    static_assert(validator<bool, 2>::validate(true), "Invalid");
}
```

I understand why the warning would occur in a normal expression context, e.g. when I would have used the following `validate` function:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
bool validate(T value) {
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(value) < N;
}
```

– In fact, that’s why I am using the specialised template in the first place (and note that the correct template specialisation is used, and the error in my first code is raised by the template argument, not inside the function in the unspecialised template). Is there a way around this warning? If not, isn’t that a bug in the compiler?

Comment: I suppose you could work around it by specializing the entire class for situations where `N` exceeds the maximal value of `T` and have `validate` return `true`.

Comment: I think it's saying that bool is either 0 or 1, so all bools are less than 2.

Comment: My gcc 4.7.2-2 didn't warn when I tried this, although maybe I used the wrong includes.

Comment: @Neil, you need `-Wtype-limits` or `-Wextra`

Comment: @KerrekSB Isn’t that what I’m doing?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Sorry, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been fixed in GCC trunk, see [PR 11856](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11856)

So wait for approximately late April and use GCC 4.8 :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since I can’t wait until this is fixed (see Jonathan’s answer) I’ve selectively disabled the warning using GCC `#pragma` extensions:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtype-limits"
static_assert(validator<bool, 2>::validate(true), "Invalid");
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Note that these pragmas unfortunately need to surround the *calling* code even though the actual error happens in the template parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround:

```
template <
    typename T,
    std::size_t N,
    bool = static_cast<std::size_t>(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()) < N>
struct validator {
    static constexpr bool validate(T value) {
        return size_t_cast(value) < N;
    }
private:
    static constexpr std::size_t size_t_cast(T value) {
        return value;
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct validator<T, N, true> {
    static constexpr bool validate(T) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

This allows the example to compile without errors in GCC 4.7.2.

Comment: No, this is equivalent to my code and has the same warning (you forgot to enable `-Wextra`!) Note that, like I said in the question, the warning is not produced by the function body – it’s produced by the template instantiation. What does work, on the other hand, is defining `size_t_cast` outside of the struct and then using it in the template list. Or, indeed, without the whole structure which is now redundant.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If you notice, I posted this answer after it was pointed out to me that I had forgotten `-Wextra`, and I tested this with `-Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: In that case, test again. Your code *does* create the same warning.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Interesting, I tried your online evaluator link and I agree that my locally installed gcc gives different results, and applying the `size_t_cast` in the way you describe is necessary for the online version.